# How can I split a file into multiple files based on pattern using perl?

Tags: perl

How can I split a file into multiple files based on pattern using perl?

Ex: input to be a .txt file, name of the output file stored in another .txt file

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation as to what the input file is like, what pattern you want to match and what output files will be created?

Comment: You need to give a little more information about what you want to accomplish for us to help you well. Also, asking for code here without showing that you even tried is poor form, although someone might give you free code anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here, to open a new file on each occurrence of the pattern `/8/`:

```
$ seq 30 | perl -pe 'BEGIN{open STDOUT, ">", "file" . ++$n}
                     open STDOUT, ">", "file" . ++$n if /8/'
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  file4
$ paste *
1       8       18      28
2       9       19      29
3       10      20      30
4       11      21
5       12      22
6       13      23
7       14      24
        15      25
        16      26
        17      27
```

Comment: I think the question was more like using `$.%4` to spread the lines in separate files. So line 1, 5, 9, … in file1, line 2, 6, 10, … in file2 and so on. Of course, just a guess.